# Why the 20.04.1 is still not available in the update manager?

Tags: upgrade

Why the 20.04.1 is still not available in the update manager ?

Comment: Run the update in the terminal and copy the error message into a text file. The error message will probably say which log file to look in to display the complete error message. An uncorrected error can block your upgrade forever, but if you correct the error the upgrade will proceed normally. **Note**: Please simulate all corrections before running them to avoid crippling your operating system.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04.1 by inputting the following into terminal:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Alternatively , you can upgrade using the gui tool by entering the following into terminal:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -f DistUpgradeViewGtk3
```